# I want to change woocomerce product tittle, image, product url dynamically for sending push notification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, push-notification, woocommerce-rest-api

I modified the code to send push notification when new product published.
So, I added hook and changed title, massage, target url, image to get the value dynamically. But It is not working.
In the theme function , I find no error. But
After publishing post. It is showing a critical error. It failed to send push notification.

**Help me by finding the fault or recommend me corrections.**

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_push_notification', 9999, 3 );
 function send_push_notification ( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( 'product' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status ) {
        global $product;

        $end_point   = 'https://api.webpushr.com/v1/notification/send/sid';
        $http_header = array( 
    "Content-Type: Application/Json", 
    "webpushrKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "webpushrAuthToken: 31669"
);  
        $req_data = array(
            'title'      => $product->get_name(),
            'message'    => 'check out now',
            'target_url' => $product->get_permalink(),
            'image'      => $product->get_image(),
            'sid'        => '113596298',
        );

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $end_point );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $req_data ) );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        $response = curl_exec( $ch );

        echo $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i add array value like this. It works. `'title'   => "Notification title", //required
    'message'   => "Notification message", //required
    'target_url' => 'https://www.webpushr.com', //required
    'sid'           => '113644184' //required. . ` But diynamic value does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the $product object here and also not using standard wp_request_post instead of cURL which is a best practice in wordpress.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'send_push_notification', 9999, 3 );
function send_push_notification ( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( 'product' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status ) {
        //global $product; //don't do this.
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); //do this instead
        $end_point   = 'https://api.webpushr.com/v1/notification/send/sid';

        //do a wp_remote_post instead of cURL

        $body = array(
            'title'      => $product->get_name(),
            'message'    => 'check out now',
            'target_url' => $product->get_permalink(),
            'image'      => $product->get_image(),
            'sid'        => '113596298',
        );
        $response = wp_remote_post( $end_point, array(
            'method'      => 'POST',
            'timeout'     => 45,
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'Application/Json',
                'webpushrKey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                'webpushrAuthToken' => '31669'
            ),
            'body' => json_encode($body), //replace it with $body if a array body is expected by the api.
        ));
     
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
            //Something went wrong
        } else {
            //Success. Store or output $response as you want.
            //use: wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) to get response body
        }
             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned your code and fixed some issues, I am not sure with which hook, you're running this function, but you must check if `$product` is null on an object when you're running this code. If you're running it on the backend, you may or may not get `$product` in some cases so check that first then debug other issues.

```php
function bbloomer_add_custom_meta_on_publish_product( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( 'product' === $post->post_type && 'publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status ) {
        global $product;

        $end_point   = 'https://api.webpushr.com/v1/notification/send/sid';
        $http_header = array(
            'Content-Type: Application/Json',
            'webpushrKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'webpushrAuthToken: xxxxx ',
        );

        $req_data = array(
            'title'      => $product->get_name(),
            'message'    => 'check out now',
            'target_url' => $product->get_permalink(),
            'image'      => $product->get_image(),
            'sid'        => '113596298',
        );

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_header );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $end_point );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $req_data ) );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        $response = curl_exec( $ch );

        echo $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many Many Thanks to you for finding the fault. I have tried it, It works. But Unfortunately, remote post is not working with image, Because, It is not sending the image url. I have tried the format. But It is not working. Here I modified something. image format should be like this ` `image'  => 'https://cdn.webpushr.com/siteassets/aRB18p3VAZ.jpeg` I modified it to get dynamically get the value. But it is not working `  'image'      => $product->get_image($attr = array( 'src'=>get_the_post_thumbnail_url())), `// Here I want to get Image thumbnail url. `